# ID number assignment by groups

Tags: sas

How can I assign `ID` numbers based on two variables, `A` and `B`. It would be helpful if the code can handle multiple variables.
Here is what my data look like:

```
A       B  ID
5000136 5 1
5000136 5 1
5000225 4 2
5000225 4 2
5000225 4 2
5000225 6 3
5000225 6 3
5000225 6 3
5000327 2 4
5000327 2 4
....
```

`ID` is the result I want to produce.
Thanks in advance and I'm sorry if this question is duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data want;
set have;
by A B;
if first.B then id+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use first.[var] processing this method can be used as well.

```
data test;
infile cards;
input a b;
retain id 0;
id = ifn(lag(b) ne b, id+1, id);
datalines;
5000136 5 
5000136 5 
5000225 4 
5000225 4 
5000225 4 
5000225 6 
5000225 6 
5000225 6 
5000327 2 
5000327 2 
;
run;

proc print; 
run;
```